# C#/Winforms, DataGridView/Combobox

Tags: c#, winforms

I am a complete C# novice & want the best way to achieve the following. I have 2 data tables

```
Table 1 - Employees  
Emp Code.....Emp Name.....Manager Cd  
1............Bill Smith......A  
2............Mick Franks.....A  
3............Joyce Watson....B  

Table 2 - Managers  
Manager Cd......Manager Name  
A...............Simon Smith  
B...............Sue Payne
```

Manager code is the foreign key in the Employees table I have a datagrid that displays the Employees table but when users add/edit the Manager Cd I would like to display a combo box that displays the Manager Name but will store the Manager Cd when selected from the list.

I'm sure this is fairly straight forward but I have spent approx 3 hours on the i/net trying to find a solution but they all seem hideously complicated.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3):

You can define a column of the DataGridView as a DataGridViewComboBoxColumn, this type of column has a property named Datasource that you can point to the dataTable containing the list of possible values.

You can find a sample of this on the [official MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcomboboxcolumn.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

The "normal" `ComboBox` has `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember` properties which you can set.  In your case you'd want to set `DisplayMember` to the manager name and `ValueMember` to the manager code.  (You'd also need to set the `DataSource` as noted by @Doliveras.)

According to the online docs (see @Doliveras' answer) these should also be available on the `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` ... but I know from personal experience that was not the case in .NET 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

```
               DataGridViewComboBoxColumn combo = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();

                combo.Name = "......";
                combo.DataPropertyName = ".....";
                DataTable dt = obj.SqlDataTable("your sql query")



                foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                {
                    combo.Items.Add(row["...."].ToString());
                }

                   dataGridView1.Columns.Add(combo);
```

This will add a combobox to ur gridview and populate that with the corresponding values from database
you can add a button to update the selected values from the dropdown/combobox into the database. This is just an idea to give you a quick start.Hope this helps.